# Best Pratice: Eclipse Project share in department (no versioning)

Tags: java, eclipse, project

I created an Java application under the use of Eclipse. Now the application will be running in production. However, if there should be a change in near future, another user of my department should be able to grab the code and improve it.

How would we achieve this, without any versioning software / repository (like SVN ors so)?

Is it a good practice for such a small bit of code, to just export the project as ZIP File and others just import them into their workspace?

Comment: You really should use a [VCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control). There are plenty of these, and they are not difficult to use.

Comment: If you need help with a very bad practice (not using any VCS), you'd need to explain why for us to be helpful. Otherwise, everyone will just point you towards a VCS. No matter how small the code base, any code base will benefit from using a VCS once it gets shared.

Comment: Simple answer: No.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not a best practice to not use any version control software. 
However, if you really want to do it there are many ways. One way I would say is by using a shared folder (assuming that you all are on the same network).
Right click on your Project on Eclipse, then export to your localhost, zip the code and copy it to the shared folder. If your folder is shared on network, others can get the updated code anytime they need it once you update the shared folder. But whoever gets the code will have to make sure that their localhost workspace is updated properly.

I would suggest, you create folders inside the shared folder like dev/tst/stg/prod and copy the code accordingly. And also make sure that you are not replacing any previous stable code in case if you want to revert the changes.

For instance, if it is dev then create a folder with today's date and copy the code changes done today so that it will be easy for any new person to get the latest code and work on.

If you are not on the same network but both got access to internet then you may use [Dropbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropbox_(service)) to share the code. Hope my response help you.